# Microsoft performance storage tier is not being used

Tags: storage-spaces

On Windows 10 I have set up tiered storage with two mirrored 512GB SSDs for the Performance tier and two mirrored 3TB hard drives for the Capacity tier. When I optimize the storage tiers it shows that the current size of the performance tier is 1.98GB. Due to a mistake during creation this tier was resized from 1.98GB to 927GB but there is still a 1.98GB number. How can I get it to use all of the SSD capacity?

Here is the output of the optimization run that shows the performance capacity at 1.98GB:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> defrag.exe /C /H /K /G

Invoking tier optimization on Storage (D:)...


Pre-Optimization Report:

    Volume Information:
            Volume size                 = 2.72 TB
            Free space                  = 1.72 TB
            Total fragmented space      = 7%
            Largest free space size     = 1.66 TB

    Note: File fragments larger than 64MB are not included in the fragmentation statistics.

The operation completed successfully.

Post Defragmentation Report:

    Volume Information:
            Volume size                 = 2.72 TB
            Free space                  = 1.72 TB

    Storage Tier Optimization Report:

            % I/Os Serviced from Perf Tier  Perf Tier Size Required
            100%                            47.17 GB *
            95%                             44.72 GB
            90%                             42.27 GB
            85%                             39.83 GB
            80%                             37.38 GB
            75%                             34.93 GB
            70%                             32.49 GB
            65%                             30.04 GB
            60%                             27.59 GB
            55%                             25.14 GB
            50%                             22.70 GB
            45%                             20.25 GB
            40%                             17.80 GB
            35%                             15.36 GB
            30%                             12.91 GB
            25%                             10.46 GB
            20%                             8.01 GB
            15%                             5.57 GB
            10%                             3.12 GB
            5%                              887.12 MB

    * Current size of the Performance tier: 1.98 GB
      Percent of total I/Os serviced from the Performance tier: 1%

    Size of files pinned to the Performance tier: 0 bytes
    Percent of total I/Os: 0%

    Size of files pinned to the Capacity tier: 0 bytes
    Percent of total I/Os: 0%
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Here is the virtual disk:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VirtualDisk

FriendlyName ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus HealthStatus    Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------ --------------------- --------------------- ----------------- ------------    ---- --------------- -----------------
Tiered Space                                             OK                Healthy      3.18 TB         6.36 TB            49.98%


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

And here are the individual tiers:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VirtualDisk "Tiered Space" | Get-StorageTier

FriendlyName          TierClass   MediaType ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy     Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------          ---------   --------- --------------------- ---------------------     ---- --------------- -----------------
Tiered Space-SSD Tier Performance SSD       Mirror                1                     463.5 GB          927 GB            50.00%
Tiered Space-HDD Tier Capacity    HDD       Mirror                1                      2.73 TB         5.45 TB            50.00%


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Thanks very much,
Mike.